# Automatic Login for WiFi Hotspot

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation

I am trying to access the internet through a WiFi Hotspot which requires login details to be entered into a web browser. It keeps disconnecting and requiring me to re-login every few minutes.

Is there a program for Ubuntu which will allow me to automatically login in the background each time this happens?

Comment: (1) What does every few minutes mean? Every new page? Every two minutes? Every hour? (2) What browser are you using? (3) Do you have anything that would block cookies or javascript?

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  My office wifi = fine.  My home wifi = fine.  McDonalds wifi = fine.  Starbucks wifi = fine.  A wifi network at a hotel (or transit bus or whatever) that firsts ask you to "accept" or "log in" their default page before you proceed to Google (or anywhere) = NOT fine.  Or fine for a minute, then NOT fine.  Zero issue with my Mac, iPhone, and Win 7 on the same wifi network.

Comment: Update - it must be the driver/card (Dell Mini 10v).  If I use a different Ubuntu laptop with the offending Wifi network - it works just fine!  Investigating a more specific answer.

Comment: This kind of access is called a "Captive portal", for reference. There are two issues here: automatically logging in to a captive portal, and the network issues on machines that keep on getting disconnected...

Answer (score 1):

For the [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) auto-login problem (not the network disconnecting issue)...

[Coova](http://www.coova.org), a captive portal implemtnation has some client tools: [CoovaFX](http://www.coova.com/CoovaFX) is a Firefox extension for doing login, and [CoovaAX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coova.android&hl=en) is an Android app. These use [WISPr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr) for authentication.

There are also [some other Android applications](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/auto+login+hotspots) for the same purpose; some are specific to certain providers, others use a particular standard.

I suspect that in most cases where a captive portal is redirecting requests to its login screen, these standards are not supported, however if they are then automating the login should be easier than with a non-standard browser screen.

There are some [very basic scripts by Laurent Gighonis](http://gouloum.fr/doc/wifi.html), but they don't look very comprehensive and probably only cover a few providers...